# How to create an OSD/Overlay like Radeon and Geforce software do in games?

Tags: windows, graphics, directx, overlay

I want text to overlay full screen games. Nvidia and AMD software manage to make their interface superimposed on any screen. How do they do it? What is the technology used? Any Windows API?

Comment: Nvidia and AMD can do anything since they write their own drivers. At our poor standard developer level, we can search on this site: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=overlay+directx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DirectX 11 Overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753311/directx-11-overlay)

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I guess you're right. They have access to the driver. Software that doesn't use hooking techniques.